# Storing and retrieving a primitive type type(?) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface, primitive-types

[I'm neither sure how to phrase my Question, nor if what I want to do makes really sense.]

I have an application where a lot of data is stored in a two-dimensional array.

It is (real world) address data, that comes from different sources/municipalities with different conventions. The Data-Array cannot have a lot of information besides the raw (CSV provided) data. (In a valid JS-Array variable)

I'm creating a 'framework' for the application that retrieves a value for each address in TypeScript...

I have successfully defined a type that describes each possible form of a single data line.

The first 1 to 4 elements relate to the address. Street-name has to be there always, a street number and up to two additions are optional. (After that at least one Element has to be provided, but that can have any number of forms and types, and there can be lots of values of a different kind.)

```
type FinderLine = [
   street: string,
   houseNumber?: number,
   numberAdd1?: string | number,
   numberAdd2?: string | number,
   ...rest: any[]
]; // does actually work in the latest versions of TypeScript!
```

I'm now working on a system that can describe each cell so that my frame can use it as a kind of configuration. The configuration/description object is supposed to be an array that has an object of type *FinderCellDescription* for each 'cell'.

It should look like dataDescription:FinderCellDescription[] = [{}, {} ...];

Background: Basically there are (for now) 4 types of cell-data LOCATER: address data possible 1 to 4 to identify one single address, VALUE data, that can be a directly used number or one that has to be matched somehow, DESCRIPTROR data, that is needed only for display purposes, and SET data, that needs to be used with other data in the same set...

As you can see, the address additions can either be of type number or of type string.

Some cities use A 'Highstreet 20a' others B 'Flower-Lane 34 / 2'. My dataDescrition interface looks like this: (I left out FinderCellDescription to not complicate things further unnecessarily - I guess you get the idea anyhow.)

```
interface FinderCellLocator extends FinderCellDescription{
   type: 'LOCATOR';
   primitive: keyof number | keyof string;
   prefix?: string;
   descriptiveName: string;
}
```

The critical part is the **primitive** I would like to define in the actual object the type that is used in that particular city/dataset.
The primitive property should not hold a value of either type, but a representation of the **type itself**.
The *keyof* or *typeof* tries didn't work.
It's probably not to hard to work around the problem in the actual situation, but I felt, that I wanted to understand how to do something like that, or if it is even possible.

As mentioned in my comment I wasn't jet sure of how to implement what I was looking for. I've created an example that might help to clarify:

```
type FinderLine = [
    street: string,
    houseNumber?: number,
    numberAdd1?: string | number,
    numberAdd2?: string | number,
    ...rest: any[]
];


enum FinderCellTypes{
    LOCATOR,
    VALUE,
    DESCRIPTOR
}

type FinderCellType = keyof typeof FinderCellTypes;

interface FinderCellDescription {
    cellType: FinderCellType;
    descriptiveName: string;
}

interface FinderCellLocator extends FinderCellDescription{
    cellType: FinderCellType;
    dataType: string;
    prefix?: string;
    printFunction: (x:`${dataType}`) => string  //<---HERE!
}
const street:FinderCellLocator = {
    cellType: 'LOCATOR',
    descriptiveName: 'Street Name',
    dataType: 'string',
    printFunction: printStreet
}

function printStreet (name:String){
 return name.toLocaleUpperCase();
}
```

As you can see at the marked line (<--HERE!) this is obviously not working (I also tied using an abstract class instead of an interface, but that's also not helping).

I will need various evaluation functions (simulated through the print function right now) those functions will have to be adjusted and or rewritten for most cities, by implementing a system like that I try to prevent accidents. I want to get an error, when I pass a function that expects a number as parameter to a cell that has a string in it.

Comment: What values do you want the primitive `primitive` to hold *at runtime*?  Are they the strings `"number"` or `"string"`?  If so then you are looking for [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"number" | "string"`.   Or are they something else?

Comment: It is unconventional to give interface and type names with an initial lowercase letter.  Please consider changing your interface and type names to be in UpperPascalCase (like `FinderLine` instead of `finderLine`) to conform to standard naming conventions and to avoid distractions.

Comment: @jcalz I'll consider the Capital Case for future Postings here, for my own projects I still consider following my own conventions though. The question about what values to pass  at runtime is actually a very good one. I wanted to use the wohle concept primarily to  help me while programming - as type-ifo is lost with transpiling anyhow. But in this case it is a valid question... Thanks.

Comment: You can [edit] your post, you don’t have to wait for future postings.

Comment: @jcalz I hope my question is conventional enough now.

Comment: The key thing here is jcalz's question "What values do you want the primitive primitive to hold at runtime?" which I don't think you've answered (or, if you have, I don't understand). Showing an example of the data and/or explaining how you plan to make use of the `primitive` property at runtime  might help.

Comment: @Quentin actually the more I think about it, I did not want to use it at runtime, as there s no use for it in JavaScript, I wanted to use it in some way to ensure that my evaluation functions deal with the right type. As assigning the type in in the data-array is not an option - I have to admit, that I'm not yet at the point where I have an actual implementation I just thought, that somehow declaring what datatype a cell holds can/will be useful later on. I surely can work around that but... I'll come back later with either a more concrete question or my solution. Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to define your types, then have `type ThingItCouldBe = AThing | AnotherThing | YetAnotherThing` and then write a [typeguard](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#user-defined-type-guards).

Comment: I edited the question and hope that clarifies the situation. @Quentin I'm not sure if that is type guards the way I want to go, or have to, but I will think into that direction too.

Comment: Is there a reason the type of the argument can't just be: `(x: string | somethingElse) => ...`?

Comment: @Quentin - yes, because that would allow the print function (later on the evaluation functions) to be a function that could not handle the data that's inside the described cell.